# How to convert MailChimp designed campaign into a template in Mandrill?

Tags: email, mailchimp, transactional-email, mandrill

I want to convert my MailChimp campaign into Mandrill template. So that I can use the MailChimp template to send Mandrill transactional email. I designed the campaign with drag-n-drop tools in Mailchimp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To copy a MailChimp campaign into Mandrill template you have to:

1. Log in MailChimp and go in 'Campaigns'
2. Click on 'My templates'
3. Go on the template you want to copy on Mandril and select 'edit code'
4. Copy the code and paste it in http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css
5. Convert the code and copy
6. Go on a new Mandrill template and paste the code ^^

Comment: The new option `Send to Mandrill` doesn't do the step 4 and 5 outlined above. This worked for me.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid.

Answer (score 3):

sorry you cannot convert Drag-N-Drop designed mailchimp campaign into template.

Comment: Any other way to send the campaign to Mandrill?

Answer (score 3):

According to the current Mailchimp interface (October 2014)
The only place I found the `Send to Mandrill` option was:

1. click on `Templates` in left menu bar
2. For given template, find the `Send to Mandrill` option in the drop-down to the right (next to the `Edit` button.